# Memory Leakage in Deep Copy C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand Deep Copy and write this program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
char a[10];
class String
{
    public:
    char *ptr;
        String()
        {
            ptr = a;
        }
        void setString(const char *str)
        {
            strcpy(ptr,str);
        }   
        void operator=(String k){
            ptr = new char[10];
            strcpy(ptr, k.ptr);
        }
        char* getString()
        {
            return ptr;
        }
};
class student
{
    public:
    String name;
        student(){  }
        student (const student &O){
            name=O.name;
        }
};
int main(){
    student obj;
    obj.name.setString("ABC");
    student obj1=obj;
    obj1.name.setString("NEW");
    cout << obj.name.getString() << endl;
    cout << obj1.name.getString() << endl;
}
```

It's working fine. But I'm trying to call Destructor to free the memory and when I write `Destructor` then program not run properly.

```
~String(){
            delete ptr;
        }
```

I know it's could be due to `ptr = a;` I already tested with other short examples and ptr=a caused the problem when `Destructor` called.

1. Is everything fine instead of Destructor?
2. How I can free the memory?

**Note:** This Program is just to understand the Deep copy.

Comment: Think a little bit about your default constructor for a while. It makes `ptr` point to the global array `a` (though I don't see the reason for this) which you haven't allocated. What do you think would happen when you try to delete that memory? Also, you `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, I already write that there could be problem. But I want to ask, is there any memory leakage? if yes then How I can solve that problem.

Comment: You need to [**read this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) and do a little more research afterward.

Comment: Every time the assignment operator is called you have a memory leak (unless you `delete[]` the previously allocated memory). And possible *undefined behavior* is the source string is longer than nine characters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So after `strcpy(ptr, k.ptr);` this line (in = operator) I'm thinking about to add `delete ptr;` that could solve the problem? I already tried and program worked, But just confirming about memory leakage.

Comment: Once again, think about what `ptr` is initially assigned to point to. And `delete` is not the same as `delete[]`. And deleting the memory *after* you just allocated it, what's the point of that?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh sorry by mistake.. `delete[] ptr;` would be ok ( in = operator) ? that could solve the memory leakage problem?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry may be I'm bothering you, But it's urgent.. `delete[] ptr;` would be ok ( in = operator) ? that could solve the memory leakage problem in this program?

Comment: Yes, ***iff*** you have allocated the memory in the first place, and remember that there's one case where you haven't.

Answer (score 2):

having a destructor would help - but as was pointed out in comments you have inconsistent handling of the internal storage (sometimes pointing to global sometimes pointing to dynamic mem)

so some of the things you really want to consider are:

- use consistent allocation scheme
- use NULL when not allocated
- add a destructor